# Show the closure of a subset of a complete metric space is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

"Let $A$ be a subset of a complete metric space.  Assume that for all $ε > 0$, there exists a compact set $A_ε$ so that $∀ x ∈ A, d(x, A_ε)<ε$. Show that $A$'s closure is compact."

I am trying to prove it with "Cauchy sequences in complete metric space are convergent" and "sequential compact set is compact". But I do not know how to prove all sequence in A(or A's closure?) has a cauchy subsequence.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would suggest taking the intersection of all sets $A_\varepsilon$. At first glance, this looks like the closure of $A$.

Comment: @Lubin why would any finite subfamily of these $A_\varepsilon$ intersect?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, it seems, after a second glance, that my suggestion is worthless. Thanks for encouraging me to think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best proof is to use total boundedness. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then $A_{\epsilon /2}$ is compact, hence totally bounded. You can cover it by  a finite number of open balls of radius   $\epsilon /2$. Call these balls $B(x_i,\epsilon /2), 1\leq i \leq n$. Then verify that $A$ is covered by the balls $B(x_i,\epsilon ), 1\leq i \leq n$. It follows that $A$ is totally bounded. Since $X$ is complete it follows that the closure of $A$ is compact. [ My comment below may be useful here].

Comment: One also needs to remark that the closure of a totally bounded set is still totally bounded.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am using a theorem which says that the closure of a subset $A$ of  a complete metric space is compact iff $A$ is totally bounded. Yes, the proof of this uses the fact that closure of totally bounded set is totally bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 Assume that $A$ is a closed set : If $x_\alpha$ is a sequence in $A$,
then for $1$ there is a compact set $A_1$ s.t. $d(x_\alpha,y_\alpha
)< 1 $ for some $y_\alpha \in A_1$. Since $y_\alpha\rightarrow y\in
A_1$, then $|y-x_\alpha| \leq |y-y_\alpha | + |y_\alpha - x_\alpha |
\leq 2  $ for infinitely many $\alpha$.

Here we choose any $z_1=x_\alpha$ and repeatedly we have $z_k$ i.e.
$|z_i-z_j|\leq \frac{4}{N} $ for all $i,\ j\geq N$. Hence $z_k$ is a
**Cauchy sequence** so that $z_k\rightarrow z\in A$. Hence $A$ is
compact.

Case 2 Assume that $A$ is not closed : For $\varepsilon
>0$ and any $\overline{x}$ in the closure $\overline{A}$ there is $
x\in A$ s.t. $d( x,\overline{x})< \varepsilon$. Hence $$ d(
\overline{x},x_\varepsilon )\leq d(\overline{x},x) +
d(x,x_\varepsilon )\leq 2\varepsilon
$$ for some $x_\varepsilon\in A_\varepsilon$. Hence we complete the proof.